# pip install PyRQA in Google colab

Tags: gpu, google-colaboratory

Hope someone can help me, when I try to install and run PyRQA in colab in the GPU runtime and  after run the next code:

```
pip install PyRQA

from pyrqa.time_series import TimeSeries
from pyrqa.settings import Settings
from pyrqa.analysis_type import Classic
from pyrqa.neighbourhood import FixedRadius
from pyrqa.metric import EuclideanMetric
from pyrqa.computation import RQAComputation
from pyrqa.computation import RPComputation
from pyrqa.image_generator import ImageGenerator
```

give me the next error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-2-6c56a517e983> in <module>()
      4 from pyrqa.neighbourhood import FixedRadius
      5 from pyrqa.metric import EuclideanMetric

----> 6 from pyrqa.computation import RQAComputation
      7 from pyrqa.computation import RPComputation
      8 from pyrqa.image_generator import ImageGenerator

6 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyopencl/tools.py in <module>()
     35 from decorator import decorator
     36 from pytools import memoize, memoize_method
---> 37 from pyopencl._cl import bitlog2  # noqa: F401
     38 from pytools.persistent_dict import KeyBuilder as KeyBuilderBase
     39 

ImportError: /usr/lib64-nvidia/libOpenCL.so.1: version `OPENCL_2.1' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyopencl/_cl.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Some days ago it works fine, but after yesterday it doesn't work anymore

Comment: As you can probably see from the error trace too, the problem is in pyopencl. Perhaps an update has disrupted backwards compatibility and the package's developers have not got to doing anything about it yet. by A_A (from other post)

Comment: have you tried again the next day it seems to work for me

Comment: You're right, today I checked it and it works correctly thank you very much.